JSON parsing and CircleAvatar
I have written a code to read image name and URI from JSON file.
And use the image URI to render the image via CircleAvatar.
But I am getting null value. Can you please review the code and see where I am doing wrong.
With simple array value and using List.builder, this is working fine
But this is not working in Listview with Json parsed return string.
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   HomePage({super.key});
   var jsonData;
   Future<void> loadJsonAsset() async {
     final String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/asset.json');
     var data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
          jsonData = data;
     print(jsonData[0]['assetURI']);
     print(jsonData);
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadJsonAsset();
    var arrabc = ["assets/images/bath.png",'assets/images/brush.png', 'assets/images/vihaan.png'];

    return Scaffold(

      body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return CircleAvatar(
    **      //This is displaying the data
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(arrabc[index]),
          //This is not  displaying the data - runtime exception
        //backgroundImage: AssetImage(jsonData[0]['assetURI']),**
          maxRadius: 30,
        );
      },
      itemCount: arrabc.length,
          )
      );
  }
 }

When I run the code via jsonData[0]['name'] in CircleAvatar, it is throwing runtime excpetion as throwing null.
But the same is working with array value arrabc[index].
Please suggest what I am doing wrong.
arrabc is working while jsonData is not working.

Can you write the full error or exception.

The problem is that loadJsonAsset is an async function. It won't be finished executing before jsonData is accessed.
Something like this might work for you:
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List jsonData = [];

  Future<void> loadJsonAsset() async {
    final String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/asset.json');
    setState(() {
      jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadJsonAsset();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(jsonData[index]['assetURI']),
              maxRadius: 30,
            );
          },
          itemCount: jsonData.length,
    ));
  }
}


Thanks Ivo. Any specific reason, you made it stateful widget. I have been trying to execute the logic via stateless

Because of the asynchronous loading of the data you will have a state of before loading is finished and after it's finished.

It is throwing error "No Directionality widget found.
Scaffold widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Directionality ancestor was: Scaffold
"

That means you probably are not wrapping all in a MaterialApp
